# High erlang process memory executing mnesia:dirty_select/2

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia, ets

I have an mnesia table `gen_saga_persist` which is queried by a process every 1 second.

The function used is `mnesia:dirty_select(gen_saga_persist, [{#gen_saga_persist{id = '$1', app = undefined, partition = 33, execution_type = auto, _ = '_'}, [], ['$1']}])`

Now as the table grows, i observed my process querying this table grows in terms of memory. Can anyone help me understand why my process memory is increasing (mnesia newbie here), as i am not even storing the result in my process data or anywhere.

Mnesia table info:

```
[{access_mode,read_write},
 {active_replicas,[server@localhost]},
 {all_nodes,[server@localhost]},
 {arity,12},
 {attributes,[id,partition,app,type,subtype,name,status,
              execution_type,retry_count,update_time,controller_state]},
 {checkpoints,[]},
 {commit_work,[{index,ordered_set,
                      [{{9,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76896>}},
                       {{8,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76882>}},
                       {{7,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964163.74776>}},
                       {{6,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76856>}},
                       {{5,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79429>}},
                       {{4,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79409>}},
                       {{3,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76810>}}]}]},
 {cookie,{{1632211298276938000,-576460752303418559,1},
          server@localhost}},
 {cstruct,{cstruct,gen_saga_persist,ordered_set,[],
                   [server@localhost],
                   [],[],0,read_write,false,
                   [{3,ordered},
                    {4,ordered},
                    {5,ordered},
                    {6,ordered},
                    {7,ordered},
                    {8,ordered},
                    {9,ordered}],
                   [],false,gen_saga_persist,
                   [id,partition,app,type,subtype,name,status,execution_type,
                    retry_count,update_time,controller_state],
                   [],[],[],
                   {{1632211298276938000,-576460752303418559,1},
                    server@localhost},
                   {{2,0},[]}}},
 {disc_copies,[server@localhost]},
 {disc_only_copies,[]},
 {external_copies,[]},
 {frag_properties,[]},
 {index,[9,8,7,6,5,4,3]},
 {index_info,{index,ordered_set,
                    [{{9,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76896>}},
                     {{8,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76882>}},
                     {{7,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964163.74776>}},
                     {{6,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76856>}},
                     {{5,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79429>}},
                     {{4,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79409>}},
                     {{3,ordered},{ram,#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76810>}}]}},
 {load_by_force,false},
 {load_node,server@localhost},
 {load_order,0},
 {load_reason,local_only},
 {local_content,false},
 {majority,false},
 {master_nodes,[]},
 {memory,2455944},
 {ram_copies,[]},
 {record_name,gen_saga_persist},
 {record_validation,{gen_saga_persist,12,ordered_set}},
 {size,7747},
 {snmp,[]},
 {storage_properties,[]},
 {storage_type,disc_copies},
 {subscribers,[]},
 {type,ordered_set},
 {user_properties,[]},
 {version,{{2,0},[]}},
 {where_to_commit,[{server@localhost,disc_copies}]},
 {where_to_read,server@localhost},
 {where_to_wlock,{[server@localhost],false}},
 {where_to_write,[server@localhost]},
 {wild_pattern,#gen_saga_persist{id = '_',partition = '_',
                                 app = '_',type = '_',subtype = '_',name = '_',status = '_',
                                 execution_type = '_',retry_count = '_',update_time = '_',
                                 controller_state = '_'}},
 {{index,3},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76810>},
 {{index,4},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79409>},
 {{index,5},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964161.79429>},
 {{index,6},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76856>},
 {{index,7},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964163.74776>},
 {{index,8},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76882>},
 {{index,9},#Ref<0.3472765205.1199964162.76896>}]
```

Process info:

```
[{current_function,{timer,sleep,1}},
 {initial_call,{bin_updates_dispatcher,poll_func,3}},
 {status,waiting},
 {message_queue_len,0},
 {links,[]},
 {dictionary,[]},
 {trap_exit,false},
 {error_handler,error_handler},
 {priority,normal},
 {group_leader,<105603.71.0>},
 {total_heap_size,4781410},
 {heap_size,1199557},
 {stack_size,6},
 {reductions,155758726},
 {garbage_collection,[{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}},
                      {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},
                      {min_heap_size,233},
                      {fullsweep_after,65535},
                      {minor_gcs,11}]},
 {suspending,[]}]
```

Process function:

```
poll_gen_saga_persist_table(Delay) ->
    Pid = spawn(bin_updates_dispatcher, poll_func, [Delay, gen_saga_persist,
                [{#gen_saga_persist{
                    id = '$1', app = undefined, partition = 33, execution_type = auto, _ = '_'
                }, [], ['$1']}]]),
    unlink(Pid),
    Pid.

poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]) ->
    mnesia:dirty_select(TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]),
    timer:sleep(Delay),
    poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not related with mneisa, it's caused by your `poll_func`. It's running forever in the self-loop.

```
poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]) ->
    mnesia:dirty_select(TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]),
    timer:sleep(Delay),
    poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]). <--- it can't release any memory.
```

You can rewrite the following code by `gen_server` by using `timer:send_after message`

```
Pid = spawn(bin_updates_dispatcher, poll_func, [Delay, gen_saga_persist,
                [{#gen_saga_persist{
                    id = '$1', app = undefined, partition = 33, execution_type = auto, _ = '_'
                }, [], ['$1']}]]),
```

and simplifize `poll_func`

```
poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]) ->
        mnesia:dirty_select(TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]).
```

Therefore for the pid, the memory caused by `dirty_select` will be released after completing the calling, and be reused in the next loop.

Comment: My initial problem was that of a gen_statem process only and then I did an experiment with a plain process to pinpoint the issue. So I don't think converting to gen server will help.

Comment: In the mnesia.erl source code, and related rpc.erl,  you can find the answer. The code show that your calling causes some codes still in your process, they are invisible in your spawn code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a stop condition for this function:

```
poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]) ->
    mnesia:dirty_select(TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]),
    timer:sleep(Delay),
    poll_func(Delay, TableName, [{MatchSpec, Guards, Return}]).
```

Because you are calling poll_func function one more time and it will go to loop forever without a stop condition.